# Unable to run SonarQube 6.1, Ubuntu 14, Open Java 1.7.0_111, MySQL 5.7

Tags: sonarqube, ubuntu-14.04

I think I have properly setup the MYSQL and tried running sonarQube, but I get below error in **sonar.log** file.

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

WrapperSimpleApp: Unable to locate the class org.sonar.application.App: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/application/App : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
  java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class} [app_arguments]

Where:
  app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
  app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
                  application.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Upon executing **start** and **status**,

```
emgda@ubuntu:~/sonarqube-6.1/bin/linux-x86-64$ sudo ./sonar.sh start
Starting SonarQube...
Started SonarQube.
emgda@ubuntu:~/sonarqube-6.1/bin/linux-x86-64$ sudo ./sonar.sh status
SonarQube is not running.
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should scroll to the far right of your log snippet. The actual error is there: `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

It's telling you you need to upgrade to Java 8.

Comment: Thank you so much to look after my issue. I will update on this soon.